# Options to disable cascade without removing annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Hi can any one help me with the below issue

I have a parent object say `ParentObj` and it has two child objects like `ChildObj1` and `ChildObj2` as below

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="parent")
    public class ParentObj {
      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="child1_id", nullable=false)
        private Child childObj1;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="child2_id")
        private Child childObj2;
    }
```

I have used **cascade=CascadeType.ALL** because when I save parent object I want to save child objects also thats working fine (I dont want to explicitly save child and then setting them to parent and then saving parent)

and `Child` object is like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child extends Persistent{
        @Column(name="email")
        private String email;
}
```

and in db level I have set email as unique constraint as below

```
 UNIQUE KEY `uk_email` (`email`)
```

I receive **email** fields from front-end jsp issue is when childObj1 email and childObj2 email is same I am getting unique key constraint violation exception because there is unique key constraint in db level but the above modal working fine if both emails are different.

Is there any way to handle the above issue without removing cascade type in object level and without removing unique constraint in db level, something like disabling annotation only in this case without removing annotation not sure whether we can do it or not

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for but in what way would removing the cascade help you? I'd probably check the emails before trying to persist the parent and refuse to do so if both are equal.

Comment: Even I need to save the parent object if both emails are same I just can ignore that case but the child object should be saved only once and the table in db should look like



parent table
=============
child1_id :1
child2_id: 1

Comment: Hibernate can't help you with this so you'll have to handle that yourself. Check before and remove the second child if email addresses are equal (or set `childObj2 = childObj1`).

Comment: so you are saying that we should not save child2 if both are same right?

Comment: As this seems to be an "expected problem" based on invalid user input, I think the correct way is to catch the constraint exception, and report back to the front-end. Trying to find a workaround doesn't make sense IMO as you don't **want** to store two identical children?

Comment: according to our business its a valid case because below is our usecase;

if suppose parent is ebook and child1 is sender and child 2 recipient and sender can send ebook to recipient  what if the case if he wants to send to recipient but recipient email is not available with him at that time so thought to give his email address as recipient my modal case in this case

Comment: If you _really_ want child1 and child2 to point to the same entity then you should do so before saving. Otherwise just remove child2 or refuse to save in the first place - which one you choose depends on your actual requirements (not what you _want_ to do but what you _need_ to do).

Comment: @Thomas thanks for reply, I have thought of those two points but still I want to know whether is there any way of resolving this

Comment: Did you try checking manually and setting `child2 = child1` before saving?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas just now I have tried this its working pretty good and that is what exactly I want my problem solved :) thanks once again